# Running multiple android emulators in AWS

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

Is there a solution to this?

It seems Android emulator needs hardware acceleration to run smoothly which you can't get on AWS.

Clearly, appetize.io is using multiple cloud based emulators ( https://appetize.io/demo?device=nexus9&scale=50&orientation=portrait&osVersion=5.1)

Comment: Why use a simulator when you can run multiple real devices - https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/ ?

Comment: @Guy device farm is headless afaik , i want to navigate the device